# More efficient way to save multiple dependent objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

One a single view, I have to create 3 objects which are dependent one from the other. My guess is that doing 3 database queries is extremely inefficient. Is there a better way of doing it?

```
character = char(user = request.user, race = form.clean_race())
character.save()

colony = colony(char = character)
colony.save()

buildings = colony_building(colony = colony, building_5 = 1)
buildings.save()
```

`

Comment: How 3 queries to insert one record each in three tables is inefficient? Is there a query in SQL to do it more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are different models, you will need one SQL query per model, because SQL's `INSERT` can only target one table. So doing 3 queries for 3 models is OK to me.